# Returning the next specific date

Tags: javascript, date

Let's say there is a lottery draw takes place twice weekly on a Wednesday and a Saturday at 8pm. I am writing a function that calculates and returns the next valid draw date based on the current date and time and also on an optional supplied date time parameter.

I have written a function like below but how can I improve this? For example how can I avoid using `getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, 6)` twice?

```
function getLotteryDrawDate(date) {
    var lotteryDrawDate = new Date(date || new Date());
    if (lotteryDrawDate.getDay() < 4) {
        // get next wednesday
        getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, 3);

        // get next saturday
        if (lotteryDrawDate.getHours() >= 20) {
            getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, 6);
        }
    } else {
        // get next saturday
        getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, 6);
    }
    lotteryDrawDate.setHours(20, 00, 00);
    return lotteryDrawDate.toLocaleString();
}

function getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, iterator) {
    return lotteryDrawDate.setDate(lotteryDrawDate.getDate() + (iterator - lotteryDrawDate.getDay()));
}

var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1);

var nextThursday = new Date();
nextThursday.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 3);

console.log(getLotteryDrawDate(new Date()));
console.log(getLotteryDrawDate(tomorrow));
console.log(getLotteryDrawDate(nextThursday));
console.log(getLotteryDrawDate(new Date("2020-04-22 21:00")))
```

Comment: Side note: `new Date(someDateInstance)` is not reliable cross-browser. Use `new Date(+someDateInstance)` instead.

Comment: What part of this are you asking about, specifically?

Comment: My question was to avoid duplications such as getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, 6)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the next day and time as separate actions, consider getting them both at once.

I.e. instead of just getting the next draw date, get it with the appropriate time as well. That way you just get the next draw.

```js
function getNextDraw(date = new Date()) {
   let d = new Date(+date);
   
   // If after 8 pm, set to midnight, i.e. next day 00:00:00
   if (d.getHours > 19) {
     d.setHours(24,0,0,0);
   }
   
   // Set time to 8 pm
   d.setHours(20,0,0,0);
   
   // Get the day of the week
   let day = d.getDay();
   
   // If Sun to Tue, set to Wed
   if (day < 3) {
     d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3 - day);
     
   // If Thu to Fri, set to Sat
   } else if (day > 3 && day < 6) {
     d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6 - day);
   }
   
   // Otherwise, already set to Wed or Sat
   return d;
}

// One week's worth of dates
for (let date = new Date(2020,3,27), i=0; i<7; i++) {
  console.log(date.toString().substr(0,24) + ' : ' + getNextDraw(date).toString().substr(0,24));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Concise but less maintainable version:

```js
function getNextDraw(date = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  d.setHours(d.getHours() < 20? 20 : 24,0,0,0);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + Math.ceil((d.getDay()||1)/3)*3 - d.getDay());
  return d;
}

// One week's worth of dates
for (let date = new Date(2020,3,27), i=0; i<7; i++) {
  console.log(date.toString().substr(0,24) + ' : ' + getNextDraw(date).toString().substr(0,24));
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use momentjs in this case.

function getSpecificDay(lotteryDrawDate, iterator) {
    var currentday=new Date().getDay(); 
    var daysLeftInLottery= iterator-currentday;
    return lotteryDrawDate.setDate(moment().add(daysLeftInLottery,'d'));
}
For more detail on monmentjs https://momentjs.com/docs/
```

Comment: A good answer should address their issue and show them how to fix it, it shouldn't require a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP. :-)